# Swagger basePath is not working host is correct but still api is not working properly. why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger-ui

```js
const swaggerOptions = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    info: {
      version: "1.0.0",
      title: "Attendance System API",
      description: "Attendance System API Information",
      contact: {
        name: "Kellton Developer"
      },
      host: ["http://localhost:3000"],
      basePath: "/api/v1"
    }
  },
  schemes: ["https", "http"],
  tags: [{
    name: "login",
    description: "user can login here",
  }],
  // ['.routes/*.js']
  apis: ['./routes/index.js']
};

const swaggerDocs = swaggerJsDoc(swaggerOptions);
app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs));

app.use('/api/v1/', indexRouter);
```

[image]

It always hits **http://localhost:3000/login**
but it should be like this **http://localhost:3000/login/api/v1/login**

I guess Swagger `basePath` is not working.

Comment: Why do you have to use `apis: ` option. Why not go with path options of swagger. ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the `host` value must be written as `host: "localhost:3000"` (i.e. as a single string value instead of an array, and without the protocol).

Comment: Its Resoved guys.. thanks for the support

Comment: resolved how?? @Aman

Comment: @ChanWoo Woo could you please tell me how did you resolve this issue? I am facing the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74245238/how-to-set-basepath-for-openapi-3-0-0-swagger-ui-in-node-js