# How to set basePath for OpenAPI 3.0.0 , Swagger UI in Node.js

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have routers in my controller with openAPI annotation inline. The API is working fine but swagger URL for an endpoint is not appending the base path, due to which I am getting 403 forbidden from my API Gateways.

so, like my actual URL is **http://api-dev/test-api/v1/test?p=123**, this is working fine when I am using from UI application. But in swagger documentation when I am accessing the endpoint I am getting the URL as **http://api-dev/test?p=123**, the basePath **'/test-api/v1'** is missing, due to which I am getting forbidden in swagger documentation.

Below is my controller code test-controller.ts:

```
/**
 *@openapi
 * tags:
 *   name: Test Record
 *   description: Get Test Record
 * securityDefinitions:
 *   my_token:
 *     type: api_key
 *     name: my_token
 *     in: header
 * security:
 *   my_token: []
*/

/**
 *@openapi
 * /test:
 *   get: 
 *   tags: [Test Record]
 *   summary: ...
 *   consumes:
 *    - application/json
 *    produces:
 *    - application/json
 *    parameters: 
 *       -in: ....(parameters definitions)
 *    responses:
 *      200: ...
 *      400: ...
*/

router.get('/test',async(req:IncomingMessage,res:ServerResponse)=>{...}
```

Now I have tried to put basePath in the above annotation where tags and security token is mentioned. But it is not working

Below is my index.ts file:

```
const testController=require("./controllers/test-controller")
const options={
   definition:{
      openapi:3.0.0,
      info:{
         title: 'Test API ',
         version:'1.0.0'
      }
   },
   apis:[`${path.join(__dirname,'/controllers/*')}`]
}
const swaggerSpec=swaggerJsdoc(options);
app.use('/test-api/v1/docs',swaggerUi.serve,swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec))

app.use(`/test-api/v1`,testController)
```

I also tried to add basePath in swaggerSpec but it is not working as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, we need to put servers:[url:'/test-api/v1'] instead of basePath in swaggerDefinition.

I found the solution in the following link:
https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/issues/189